# Trigger an event from a component to an invisible component in Angular 5

Tags: angular, typescript, events, ionic3, dom-events

I have a div inside a component (child.html) and I would trigger a click event to the another (parent.html) to turn a boolean from false to true. I know it is possible using html as `<child-component [Event]></child-component>` but the child have to be invisible to the user.

Is it possible to add CSS to  from the app.css to make it invisible?
I am not sure if it is possible to make it in Angular, here is what I tried:

child.html:

```
   <div class="notif-filter" (click)="hideNotif(event)"> </div>
```

child.ts:

```
 public hideNotif(event) {
    console.log(event, 'hideNotif is fired !!');
     this.hideMe = true;
    // this.feedIsVisible = false;
   }
```

parent.html: (this one should be invisible)

```
  <child-component></child-component>
```

parent.css:

```
 app-child: { display: none }
```

parent.ts:

```
     @input event: Event (comming from the child)

    lockScreen(): void {
    this.screenLocked = true;
    this.feedIsVisible = false;    ==> *This should turn to true depending on 
    the click event in the child.html*
    this.nav.setRoot('ConnexionPage').then();
  }
```

Comment: Component communication is a very basic thing in angular and can be google'd easily. Nonetheless: https://stackblitz.com/edit/hello-angular-6-f39nzz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: @Carsten I know it is a very basic but normally you have to right some syntac in the html file to retrieve the binding property but for me I am trying without html such as `()` or `[]`

Comment: That's not an angular approach making it bad practice. What is your reasoning behind it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First read about [Angular Component Interaction](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service).

Then you will know that there are 4 main ways to communicate between components.

- [Pass data from parent to child with input binding](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#pass-data-from-parent-to-child-with-input-binding)
- [Parent listens for child event](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-listens-for-child-event)
- [Parent interacts with child via local variable](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-interacts-with-child-via-local-variable)
- https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service.

In your scenario you can use any method you want.

look at this example

**child.component.ts**

```
import { Component, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  templateUrl: './child.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./child.component.css']
})
export class ChildComponent {
  public show: boolean;

  @Output()
  public childButtonClick = new EventEmitter<boolean>();

  constructor() {
    this.show = true;
  }

  public onClick(): void {
    this.show = !this.show;
    this.childButtonClick.emit(this.show);
  }

}
```

**child.component.html**

```
<button (click)="onClick()">Child button</button>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  public show: boolean;


  constructor() {
    this.show = true;
  }
  public onChildButtonClick(value): void {
    this.show = value;
  }
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<app-child (childButtonClick)="onChildButtonClick($event)"></app-child>


<div *ngIf="show">
  This will be hidden when you click the button
  And I'm using ngIf directive
</div>

<br>
<br>

<div [ngClass]="{'hide-me': !show}">
  This will be hidden when you click the button
  And I'm using ngClass directive
</div>

<br>
<div>
  show value: {{show}}
</div>
```

**app.component.css**

```
.hide-me {
  display: none
}
```

In here I've used the **Parent listens for child event** method.
And I've created a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gc5pc4) for this.

Comment: many many thanks for your help, so I will try to take the problem to another angle:  I need to make the <app-child></app-child> invisible for the user (I also update my post)

Comment: is it possible to add css to <app-child> into the app.css ??

Comment: when do you want to hide the `app-child`

Comment: always as a css `display: none`

Comment: I'll update the stackblitz. Take a look in few minutes

Answer (score 0):

[Working Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ojkfzn)

HTML:

hello.componemt.html

```
<button (click)="onClick()">hello button</button>
```

app.component.html

```
<hello (childClick)="onChildButtonClick($event)"></hello>

{{show}}
```

TS:

hello.component.ts:

```
import { Component,Input, Output, EventEmitter, } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
 selector: 'hello',
  templateUrl: './hello.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class HelloComponent  {

  public show: boolean;

  @Output()
  public childClick = new EventEmitter<boolean>();

  constructor() {
    this.show = true;
  }

  public onClick(): void {
    this.show = !this.show;
    this.childClick.emit(this.show);
  }
}
```

app.component.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular 6';
   public show: boolean;


  constructor() {
    this.show = true;
  }
  public onChildButtonClick(value): void {
    this.show = value;
  }
}
```